# Solve for a variable in an inequality

Tags: inequality

In the following inequality 
$$n - m \left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{m}\right)^n\right) \le r$$ where $n<m$ are integers and $r$ is also a small integer, can one solve for $m$?

Thanks
D.